# VPN and facebook hack

Tags: vpn

is there any chance of being hacked on Facebook while using virtual private network? and can the provider use my account for any unfair means?

Comment: Can you add some clarification? Hacked by who? (Who's "the provider"? The VPN provider?) And in what way? (Monitor traffic/passwords? Break into your computer?) How are you using the VPN and Facebook? And with what device?

Comment: What type of 'hack'? Your Facebook account can still be hacked, and it is possible to have your computer hacked by visiting Facebook. You need to clarify what you are talking about.\

Answer (score 1):

**No.** Your connection to Facebook is not at risk when you use a VPN. That's because the communication between you and Facebook is SSL-encrypted and therefore the content cannot be read or modified by anyone in between, neither your ISP nor your VPN provider.

They can conclude *that* you use Facebook but not read or control *what* you do on Facebook.

Comment: This is not true. You don't have to use SSL/TLS inside a VPN. If they are using https, the VPN shouldn't even be necessary.

Comment: VPN+plain http still leaves you vulnerable.

Comment: This answer only addresses the connection between the user and Facebook. Is that the type of hacking that the OP is talking about?

Comment: @schroeder I understood it in the way that OP wants to know if a rogue VPN provider can tamper with his Facebook connection.

Comment: @d1str0 1. The question is about Facebook and Facebook enforces HTTPS. So OP is not vulnerable. 2. There are obviously good use cases for VPN tunnels despite using HTTPS. (Privacy enhancement.)

Comment: @Arminius default is not the same as enforce. Facebook defaults to https. It does not enforce it.

Comment: @d1str0 Facebook sends a HSTS header which is a measure to enforce HTTPS. If you mean to say that, in theory, you can still access Facebook over HTTP, then you're right. But with a modern browser it's not easily possible to connect to FB over plain HTTP. So it's reasonable to assume that OP's Facebook connection is secured. (I'll enhance the answer a little to make that assumption clearer.)

Comment: @Arminius you can also just turn it off in your settings

Comment: @d1str0 I don't think that's possible anymore.